# How does one copy environment variables from one Docker image to another?

Tags: dockerfile, environment-variables

Suppose I have a Dockerfile that starts like this.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest as app

touch qwe.txt

ENV ASD=1
```

How can I copy the environment variable to another image? I know how to do it with files but not with environment variables.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

COPY --from=app / /

# qwe.txt is now here but $ASD is not.
```

Comment: yea I want to know if this is possible too!   If I find out I'll be sure to report here.

Comment: I asked it at docker forums maybe it will get an answer. https://forums.docker.com/t/how-does-one-copy-environment-variables-from-one-docker-image-to-another/136355/1